# Вывести на экран квадрат из '*'

Tags: java

Задача заключается в том, что через цикличные операторы вывести на экран квадрат из звёздочек.
Если пользователь ввёл целочисленное 3, то нужно вывести:

```
***
***
***
```

а мой код выглядит примерно так:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            final char cr = '*';
            System.out.println(cr);
            
        }
    }
}
```

только в моём случае программа выводится как:

```
*
*
*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        System.out.print("*");
      }           
      System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: она у меня теперь в одну колонну вывела 6 звездочек

Comment: @Аврелиус Не может быть. Вы неаккуратно скопировали к себе мой код.